# Calling cloud code Parse Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Im trying to use phone number verification in my app. During sign up the user will be asked for their phone number and be sent a verification code and they will enter the code and if it matches they can proceed. I have the cloud code ready but I'm not sure how exactly to call this from the app. Any help would be appreciated

What I want to be able to do is when they enter their phone number and press continue, first check that the phone number is a valid phone number, then send the sms code. finally segue to a verification view where they enter the code, if it doesn't match display an alert, if it does, log the user in

Cloud code:

```
var twilioAccountSid = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var twilioAuthToken = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
var twilioPhoneNumber = '+1555-555-5555';
var secretPasswordToken = '1234';


var twilio = require('twilio')(twilioAccountSid, twilioAuthToken);

Parse.Cloud.define("sendVerificationCode", function(request, response) {
               var verificationCode = Math.floor(Math.random()*999999);
               var user = Parse.User.current();
               user.set("phoneVerificationCode", verificationCode);
               user.save();

               twilio.sendSms({
                              From: twilioPhoneNumber,
                              To: request.params.phoneNumber,
                              Body: "Your verification code is " + verificationCode + "."
                              }, function(err, responseData) { 
                              if (err) {
                              response.error(err);
                              } else { 
                              response.success("Success");
                              }
                              });
               });
Parse.Cloud.define("verifyPhoneNumber", function(request, response) {
               var user = Parse.User.current();
               var verificationCode = user.get("phoneVerificationCode");
               if (verificationCode == request.params.phoneVerificationCode) {
               user.set("phoneNumber", request.params.phoneNumber);
               user.save();
               response.success("Success");
               } else {
               response.error("Invalid verification code.");
               }
               });
```

This is where i call the cloud code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var continueButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var phoneNumberTextField: UITextField!
@IBAction func continueButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    var phoneNumber = self.phoneNumberTextField.text

    if phoneNumber?.utf16.count < 10 {
        displayAlert("Error", message: "You must enter a valid 10 digit US phone number including area code")
    } else {
        let params = phoneNumber
        PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("sendVerificationCode", withParameters: params, block: { (object: AnyObject?, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showVerifyUserView", sender: self)
            } else {

                // Do error handling
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use this method:

```
public class func callFunctionInBackground(function: String, withParameters parameters: [NSObject : AnyObject]?, block: PFIdResultBlock?)
```

You can call your function this way:

```
        PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("sendVerificationCode",
        withParameters: /* any needed params here, for example mobile phone*/)
        { [unowned self](object:AnyObject?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            guard error == nil else {
                //handle error
                return
            }
             // everything ok
             // notify your app that code is send successfully  

    }
```

Then when user enters the code do the same:

```
        PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("verifyPhoneNumber",
        withParameters: /* any needed params here, for example verification code*/)
        { [unowned self](object:AnyObject?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
            guard error == nil else {
                //handle wrong notification code
                return
            }
            // code is ok, notify your app verification is complete
    }
```

Don't forget to deploy your code to parse with command line utility + take into account that common way to send parameters to cloud code is to send dictionaries

**Update, how to send parameters:**

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("functionName",
            withParameters: ["phoneNumber" : phoneNumber)
            { [unowned self](object:AnyObject?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                ...


        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I updated question with what I have for calling the cloud code function. What I'm having trouble with now is setting the parameters with the phone number the user entered. Ive never worked with this so it is very confusing to me

Comment: that is why I added comment in the bottom of my answer, I've updated the answer by now with example.

Comment: How can you pass secure information, such as a session token, using this method?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've deployed your code to Parse (command line "parse deploy"), you call cloud functions using PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground().  See https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFCloud.html